# The 3D polygon generated by skyline in arcgis has no Z value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d, arctoolbox

I used the skyline tool to generate the skyline in a certain scenario, when the visible angle is less than 120°, the skyline is right, as the pic below:
[image: the skyline of 120 degree]

When the visible angle is bigger than 120, the skyline looks well, but when I select the skyline, it shows that there is a project line on the 0 level, and when I use 'Feature vertices to point' to turn the skyline into point, the points also on the 0 level, see the two pictures below:
[image: the skyline of 180 degree]

Also when all the parameters are the default:
[image: the skyline of 360 degree]

Is this the software bug or I set the wrong parameter? The arcgis version is 10.2